# Shapefile not displayed after changing projection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3832 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-2.18, natural-earth

I downloaded the shapefile for the country "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp" from the natural earth web site, and opened it with QGIS and saved is with EPSG:3832.

I restarted QGIS and opened the new saved shapefile but it was not displayed and even "Zoom to Layer" did not show anything. However, I enabled on the fly projection and changed the projection to some other (I tried EPSG:4326) and it was displayed in that projection. After that check off on the fly option or change it to EPSG :3832, it was properly displayed in EPSG:3832 and "Zoom to Layer" worked properly.

Why it wasn't displayed in the first place and it was fine after I changed CRS to some other.

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS is 2.18.1.

Comment: Where did you change the CRS of the shape file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving in the new projection, the *xmax* and *ymax* of the extent of the output layer goes to infinity and hence the error (can be seen in the *Metadata* tab of *Properties* of the shapefile). The scope of the EPSG:3832 is not for global mapping and its area use can be seen at - http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3832/

To avoid this error, I would suggest selecting the region required for analysis and saving that as a shape file in EPSG:3832 rather that the whole world.

Comment: Thank you the answer. Deleting Greenland and Antarctica solved the problem even the rest does not fit in the scope of CRS. Is the link http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3832/ correct? The scope with the red rectangle seems differ from the original scope. (Or it says "an error occured" so maybe just an error.) I checked this https://epsg.io/3832.

Answer (score 1):

For **defining projection** for Shape file, follow below steps:

1) Select menu **Vector > Data Management Tools > Define Current Projection**
2) In **Output CRS** red rectangle, press on "**...**" button to define required projection for the shape file.

[image]

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain enough. This is how I changed CRS from 4326 to 3832.